# How could I make this code more "automated"?

Tags: python

I did this code yesterday trying to test how really random are the random numbers that Python generates:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import random
print "Bienvenido al Analizador del Azar, este programa generará 100 números para aleatorios, para luego dar en tanto por ciento la cantidad de cada uno."
numeros_aleatorios = []
contador = 0
while True:
    namber = random.randint(1,10)
    numeros_aleatorios.append(namber)
    contador += 1
    if contador == 100:
        break
PR1 = float(numeros_aleatorios.count(1)) / 100
PR2 = float(numeros_aleatorios.count(2))/ 100
PR3 = float(numeros_aleatorios.count(3)) / 100
PR4 = float(numeros_aleatorios.count(4)) / 100
PR5 = float(numeros_aleatorios.count(5)) / 100
PR6 = float(numeros_aleatorios.count(6)) / 100
PR7 = float(numeros_aleatorios.count(7)) / 100
PR8 = float(numeros_aleatorios.count(8)) / 100
PR9 = float(numeros_aleatorios.count(9)) / 100
PR10 = float(numeros_aleatorios.count(10)) / 100

print "Hay exactamente un", PR1, "% de 1s"
print "Hay exactamente un", PR2, "% de 2s"
print "Hay exactamente un", PR3, "% de 3s"
print "Hay exactamente un", PR4, "% de 4s"
print "Hay exactamente un", PR5, "% de 5s"
print "Hay exactamente un", PR6, "% de 6s"
print "Hay exactamente un", PR7, "% de 7s"
print "Hay exactamente un", PR8, "% de 8s"
print "Hay exactamente un", PR9, "% de 9s"
print "Hay exactamente un", PR10, "% de 10s"
```

As you can see, I had to put PR1, PR2, PR3... manually to make every %, and then write every print to display the results. My question is, is there any way to make this more automated, so I don't have to write every line indivually? It would be very useful for my next projects.

Comment: Errrrr. Why not a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) will do all the counting for you, and use `range` to loop in the number of trials you want to run:

```
from collections import Counter

trial = 100
counts = Counter(random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(trials))
print(counts)
Counter({3: 17, 7: 12, 8: 12, 9: 12, 4: 11, 6: 9, 2: 8, 10: 8, 5: 6, 1: 5})



for i in range(1,11):
    print("Hay exactamente un {}% de {}".format(100 * counts[i] / float(trials),i))
```

Output:

```
Hay exactamente un 11.0% de 1
Hay exactamente un 6.0% de 2
Hay exactamente un 12.0% de 3
Hay exactamente un 12.0% de 4
Hay exactamente un 9.0% de 5
Hay exactamente un 4.0% de 6
Hay exactamente un 10.0% de 7
Hay exactamente un 14.0% de 8
Hay exactamente un 12.0% de 9
Hay exactamente un 10.0% de 10
```

No idea if *Hay exactamente un* is in the correct order!

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @Nekuness, no worries, definitely saves a lot of typing especially!